# C code executing conditional exp. altough cond. exp. is wrong

Tags: c

The problem is that if  x=2, y=2, z=4, I see 2<2<4 on console.Why?It is wrong actually.Why I see 2<2<4?

```
 int  main(void) {           
            int x, y, z;

            printf("Please enter 3 numbers: \n");

            scanf("%d%d%d", &x, &y, &z);

            int max=x;

            if (y > max)

                max = y;
            if (z > max)

                max = z;

            if (max == z)

                if (x < y)

                printf("%d < %d < %d\n", x, y, z); 

                else

                printf("%d < %d < %d\n", y, x, z);
```

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing for `x < y`, the negation of that is `y <= x` and not `y < x`, so your print statement is giving the wrong text.

Answer (score 0):

```
            int x, y, z;

            printf("Please enter 3 numbers: \n");

            scanf("%d%d%d", &x, &y, &z);

            int max=x;

            if (y > max) // y = 2, max = 2, so this condition is wrong

                max = y;
            if (z > max) // next step is here, z = 4, max = 2, so this condition is correct

                max = z; // next step to here, now, max = 2, z = 4;

            if (max == z) // max = 4, z = 4, this condition is correct

                if (x < y) // x = 2, y = 2, this condition is wrong

                   printf("%d < %d < %d\n", x, y, z); 

                else  

                   printf("%d < %d < %d\n", y, x, z); // next step to here
```

If you want `2 = 2 < 4`, change the last condition to:

```
           if (max == z)

                if (x < y)

                   printf("%d < %d < %d\n", x, y, z); 

                else if (x > y)

                   printf("%d < %d < %d\n", y, x, z);  

                else 
                   printf("%d = %d < %d\n", x, y, z);
```

Comment: you are welcome. If you like my answer, you can click on the check mark ("V") in the answer to accept it.